# is there a way to configure this Task.WhenAll Select with an anonymous method?

Tags: c#, .net

The following code gets all domains, and then gets all users per domain:

```
var domainNames = new string[]{ "corp-domain-1", "corp-domain-2"};
var results = await Task.WhenAll(domainNames.Select(x =>
{
    request.DomainName = x;
    GetUsersPerDomainAsync(request);
}));
if (results.First() == null) return null;
return results.SelectMany(result => result).ToList();
```

The goal is to update the DomainName property on the request for each domain.  Is there a way to do this as an anonymous method similar to the code above?  The approach used in the code above doesn't compile but I just wanted to provide an idea of what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Sure you can use an anonymous method as argument for Task.WhenAll. Just make sure your anon method produces and returns an `IEnumerable<Task>`. The `Task` objects would more or less encompass what you have now in the anon method/lambda expression for `domainNames.Select(...)`. As a side note, using the same `request` for several different simultaneous/parallel requests doesn't look like a good idea ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a Task. And following [@elgonzo's advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032237/is-there-a-way-to-configure-this-task-whenall-select-with-an-anonymous-method#comment89056944_51032237) I guess your code should look like this:

```
...
await Task.WhenAll(
    domainNames.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => 
        await GetUsersPerDomainAsync(new Request() { DomainName = x }) )
    )
);
...
```

I don't believe you can wait for a return to `results` once the return of `WhenAll` is just one `Task`. But I think the main idea is that I've suggested.

[**Take a look at this code working on dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OhtXAT).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to return something from the delegate in the `Select` method, so your code might look like this:

```
var domainNames = new string[] { "corp-domain-1", "corp-domain-2" };
var results = await Task.WhenAll(domainNames.Select(x =>
{
    request.DomainName = x;
    return GetUsersPerDomainAsync(request);
}));
if (results.First() == null) return null;
return results.SelectMany(result => result).ToList();
```